# How can I migrate an existing application to using CLI?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

We have an existing Angular 2 application that we're interested in using the CLI for its build step.

Is there any information out there on achieving this? I wasn't able to find anything other than creating projects from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

you may use `ng init` command on your existing code. you should have angular-cli globally installed.

**Option 2:**

You may create a project from scratch and then bring your code in.

Hope this helps!!